# Ionic Angular different html view for web and mobile

Tags: angular, ionic3

I started playing with Ionic to build an app for mobile and web.
Using the Ionic component the mobile version looks fine, **but I can't say the same for the web version.**
**So I was wondering if it possible to use a component with two different templates**:
one for the mobile version ( using all the ionic component) and one for web version (using the classic html tags).
I would **avoid creating a big template with a `*ngIf == isMobile()` and `*ngIf == isWeb()`** or something similar.
Does someone know some good practice?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve using ng-container with ngTemplateOutlet.

**Template (home.template.html):**

```
<ng-template #desktopElem>Here is the HTML Block for Desktop</ng-template>
<ng-template #mobileElem>Here is the HTML Block for Mobile</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="isMobile ? mobileElem : desktopElem"></ng-container>
```

**Component:**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'home',
   templateUrl: 'home.template.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{
   isMobile;

   ngOnInit(){
      this.isMobile = // use regex in browser-useragent to diff b/w mobile and desktopn
   } 
}
```